# Find string in array and get the value after an "tag"

Tags: php, string

iam not sure: is this the fastest way to check an array for an Value beginning with XXX ? And if yes, extract the value after XXX: ?

```
foreach ($result['tag'] as $value) {

        $pos = strpos($value, 'xxx:');

        if ($pos !== false) {
            $split = explode('xxx:', $value);
            $r = $split[1];
        } else {
            $r = '';
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to check `substr` vs `explode` performance !

by replace 2 lines

```
$split = explode('xxx:', $value);
$r = $split[1];
```

with

```
$r = substr($value,4);
```

i think the second is more elegant

Comment: 0,5 Seconds faster :-) Thanks